# Why do two roots of my equation disappear when I give numerical values to two parameters?

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the equation

```
(-Sqrt[1 + KE la + KE s + KE la s - Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2]]*
(1 - KE la + KE s - KE la s + Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2])- 
(-1 + KE la - KE s + KE la s + Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2])*
Sqrt[1 + KE la + KE s + KE la s + Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2]]) == 0
```

`KE` and `la` are real constants. When I use Solve on the above, it gives four symbolic roots. But when I give `KE` and `la` numerical values, it only returns two numerical roots. How can this be explained?

Comment: Some of the branches may produce complex values for certain real inputs; these do not represent valid solutions for those inputs and therefore they are not returned.

Answer (score 2):

Like Mr.Wizard says those four symbolic roots are not valid solutions for every input. Verify it like this:

```
eq = (
   (-Sqrt[
         1 + KE la + KE s + KE la s - 
          Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2]]*(1 - KE la + 
         KE s - KE la s + 
         Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2]) - (-1 + KE la -
          KE s + KE la s + 
         Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2])*
       Sqrt[1 + KE la + KE s + KE la s + 
         Sqrt[4 KE la + (1 + KE s - KE la (1 + s))^2]]) == 0
   );
sol = Solve[eq, s];
```

Now `sol` contains the four roots. If we substitute these roots for `s` in the original equation then you will notice that the equation does not simplify to `True` for two of them:

```
Simplify[eq /. sol]
```

This shows that these roots are not always solutions. Now try this:

```
eq /. sol /. {KE -> 5, la -> 5}
```

> {False, False, True, True}

With numeric input *Mathematica* can determine if the expression is true or not, but as it turns out only two of the roots represent valid solutions for these constants. I assumed `Solve` returned the two other roots because under some conditions they are valid solutions, but apparently not for all.

Comment: In fact, using `Simplify[eq/.sol]` gives the two `True`s, leaving first two equations unevaluated.

Comment: And, when the first two are solutions at all? They seem to be spurious solutions...

Comment: @Ruslan Thank you, I have updated the answer accordingly. I'm not sure about when exactly they are solutions, but I think it's reasonable to assume that there are such circumstances since `Solve` returned them. Mostly I wanted to show how we could verify that the two missing roots are in fact not valid.